# display results from timePicker in a editText field

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, timepicker, android-timepicker

I can't seem to get the results from a timePicker into an editText field.  I followed the example in the Android training guide and I can see the results from the timePicker in a log but I can't figure out how to display them in a text field (tvEndTime).

```
public class Setup extends Activity {

....

private final TextView tvEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEndTime);

....

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
        tvEndTime.setText(Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
    }
}

// show the end time timePicker dialog box fragment when user clicks buttonEndTime
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}  

....
```

At the `tvEndTime.setText()` line, I get an Eclipse error "Cannot make static reference to the non static field tvEndTime".  But I can't declare the tvEndTime as static because then I get the error at the tvEndTime declaration.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to set the text on `TextView` or on `EditText` ? Your title says you want to set text on `EditText` but your code says that you are setting it on `TextView`...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code inside onClick() event of any view you are using:

```
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(CurrentActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    editText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
```

Or:

Simply change the way you set the text to `EditText` by:

```
tvEndTime.setText(selectedHour+" : "+selectedMinute);
```

**Correction:** Make your `TextView tvEndTime` as a class variable for class `Setup`

Comment: I finally got it to work by moving the declaration of tvEndTime into the onTimeSet function.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the tvEndTime.setText arguments had no effect.  I got it to work by adding the declaration of tvEndTime into the onTimeSet function (SetEndTime is called when the user clicks a button):

```
public void SetEndTime(View v) {
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Setup.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            TextView tvEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEndTime);
            tvEndTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this `tvEndTime.setText(String.valueof(hourOfDay))` for all other follow same approach